# Left-align buttons in Vuetify

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment, vuetify.js

I have a set of buttons with icons in a floating toolbar, that looks like this:

[image]

Each is a `v-btn` (wrapped inside a `v-dialog`), along these lines (Pug):

```
v-dialog(v-model="showing" width="500")
    template(v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }")
        v-btn(v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" plain )
            v-icon.dark mdi-list-status
            | Features
```

There are no other layout elements in the toolbar.

I would like the buttons aligned on the left so that the three icons are aligned vertically. How can I achieve that?

Wrapping the controls in a `v-col` with `.text-left` did not seem to do the job.

Comment: Can you create a working demo that replicates your image output?

Comment: It would be a lot of effort to do so. Is there anything in particular that my description doesn't tell you?

Comment: An output that people can see tells more than the description. Until then how can people debug what you see? Try to use https://codesandbox.io/